# Difference Between arr1.concat(arr2) And [].concat(arr1, arr2)

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, concatenation

In JavaScript, I've encountered code written in two primary ways for concatenating two (or more) arrays that employ the [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method on the [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) object. (Assume, in what follows, that `arr1` and `arr2` are generic arrays given as the arguments to the `.concat()` method). At times, I see

```
arr1.concat(arr2)
```

while, at others, I see the following used:

```
[].concat(arr1, arr2)
```

I have not, in practice, found there to be any observable difference between the two manners of expression. Neither mutates the original array(s). Both return an identical output.

What differences, if any, are there? Is one more performant over the other? Do Best Practices advise one in particular?

Many thanks for all help/feedback!

**EDIT**

Shoutout for the [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/array-concatenation-3/1) benchmarking test. It seems, as was noted by some in comments, that `arr1.concat(arr2)` is the preferred (and more natural syntax) as compared to `[].concat(arr1, arr2)`. (I suppose that comes a bit subjectively, but feel most would agree in retrospect). Even so, there's added value to be had in choosing the former syntax over the latter if for no other reason than the marginally improved performance that it comes with.

Comment: There is indeed no difference.

Comment: object oriented vs not OO style is the difference I guess

Comment: `Array#concat` is analogous to `Object.assign`, which modifies the first parameter, which could cause confusion. My guess is that `[].concat(...)` is either (a) a mistake by people who don't realise it doesn't modify the original array or (b) deliberate to make it clear to someone reading the code that the original array is not modified.

Comment: [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/array-concatenation-3/1)

Comment: @lonesomeday, no idea what you're talking about. neither of them mutate

Comment: @StephenBugsKamenar `Object.assign(obj1, obj2)` modifies the first parameter. I can see how someone would assume by analogy that `Array#concat` would as well, even though it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, using `[].concat(arr1, arr2)`, you are setting by default that the result has to be an array. You can concat strings and arrays or just strings or only arrays - and the result will be always an array.

If you wish the result to be a `string` - use empty quotation marks instead of empty array at the beginning.

```js
console.log([].concat([1,2,3], 'text'));
console.log([].concat('text', 'new'));
console.log(''.concat([1,2,3], [4,5,6]));
```

Using `arr1.concat(arr2)`, the type of the first element - in this case - `arr1`, will be the default type of newly made object. So if `arr1` is a string, even if `arr2` is an array - the result wil be typeof `string`.

```js
console.log([1,2,3].concat('text'));
console.log('text'.concat([1,2,3]));
```

In both cases - the original arrays or strings are not being mutated.

About the performance - there are no notable differences between them.

Answer (score 1):

If both `arr1` and `arr2` are plain arrays, there is absolutely no difference. It's merely two notations for the same thing, one more object-oriented and the other more functional. One might argue that `[].concat(…)` is less efficient because it has to construct and iterate an empty array, but that should hardly be measurable.

The difference is observable though when `arr1` is *not* an `Array`. Obviously it might call a different `concat` method then, or even throw when there is none (or when `arr1` is `null` or `undefined`); but also when it calls the `Array.prototype.concat` method the `arr1` won't be [checked for being spreadable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/isConcatSpreadable).